# Why called function always appear on top instead of below

Tags: python, python-3.x, upload, streamlit, function-call

So I am trying to call a streamlit upload button when a function call is triggered in st.button. But the upload button always get called on top of the button instead of below it. Any one have idea how to achieve it. Would help alot, Thnx!

```
import streamlit as st


def proc():
    st.file_uploader('')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    option = st.selectbox(
        'Which folder would you like to upload to?',
        ('1 docx-raw', '2 docx-text-only'), on_change=proc)

    st.write('You selected:', option)
```

Here, i need the upload button below it after triggering it's function
[image: screenshot]

Comment: Please clarify your question. It looks confusing. What is it that you want? Your question goes back and forth without any clarity. The image also looks misleading with your code.

Answer (score 2):

I have a workaround..By introducing one more option.

```
import streamlit as st
def proc():
    st.file_uploader('')
    
option = st.selectbox('Which folder would you like to upload to?',
                      ('','1 docx-raw', '2 docx-text-only'),format_func=lambda x: 'Select an option' if x == '' else x)
if option=='2 docx-text-only':
    proc()
    st.write('You selected:', option)  
elif option=='1 docx-raw':
    proc()
    st.write('You selected:', option)
```

This will give file uploader box below the select box.
[image]

Comment: Its simple and working, thanx !

Comment: You were right @mrin9san

Answer (score 1):

Your question is not clear enough, but from my understanding, you want to do one of these two approches.
***First approach:***

```py
import streamlit as st

def proc():
    upload_options = ['1 docx-raw', '2 docx-text-only']
    option = st.selectbox('Which folder would you like to upload to?', upload_options)
    st.write('You selected:', option)
    if option == upload_options[0]:
        upload_file = st.file_uploader('1 docx')
        if upload_file is not None:
            upload_button = st.button('Upload File', key="1 docx")
            if upload_button:
                # Do something with the file
                st.success("File Uploaded Successfully to 1 docx-raw")
    elif option == upload_options[1]:
        upload_file = st.file_uploader('2 docx')
        if upload_file is not None:
            upload_button = st.button('Upload File', key="2 docx")
            if upload_button:
                # Do something with the file
                st.success("File Uploaded Successfully to 2 docx-text-only")


def main():
    proc()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

**Output:**
[image]

***Second approach:***

```py
import streamlit as st

def proc():
    upload_file = st.button('Upload File')
    if upload_file:
        st.file_uploader('')


def main():
    option = st.selectbox(
        'Which folder would you like to upload to?',
        ('1 docx-raw', '2 docx-text-only'))
    st.write('You selected:', option)
    proc()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

**Output:**
***Button not clicked***
[image]

***Button clicked***
[image]

Comment: I feel, he wants the file up-loader to appear on bottom, on selection of the selectbox option itself, and after that he wants the "file upload" button below the "file up-loader".

Comment: You mean when he select a particular item in `st.selectbox()`, a `file_uploader` widget should appear at the bottom of the `selectbox`? Why will he want **file upload button** after haven displayed file **upload widget**?

Comment: He may want to upload file to two different destination - 1 docx-raw', '2 docx-text-only'. So when he choose an option in selectbox, respective file uploader will appear..may be something like that.

Comment: That can be fixed with four lines of codes. And after user uploads the file he Should be able to click a button. Which is like the user is submitting a file through upload. right?

Comment: His screenshot is misleading, it shows something else. I am just assuming what he wants.

Comment: sorry guys, yeah the screenshot is little misleading cause its shows the download button, still the idea is same. Both of your answer is working. Thanks alot. I couldnt tick both answer at the same time. So I ticked useful mark.